# Detecting arbitrary shapes in a scanned image

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'm working with Emgu CV to determine whether or not an area of an image contains some arbitrary shape. I'm new to both the Open and Emgu libraries (and their communities), and fear am over my head, but here goes.

The images are scanned forms (paper documents), where the "user" circles/checks/blarfs a given area. For example, let's say i have a simple paper form which contains one group with three items. The group is "gender", and the available choices are "male", "female", and "other". User X writes a check mark through "female"; user Y circles "other"; and user Z draws a nice unicorn next to "male".

Now, I have examples of forms where no marks exist. I simply use a nested template match to 1) find the "gender" group, and 2) find the item (male, female, other) within the gender group's sub image (performance is secondary to accuracy right now). Then I blur (Gaussian) and binarize the resultant image(thresholding tuned per form), and take a 2 bin histogram. I compare the normalized template and observed histograms, and get a Boolean result (true: arbitrary shape present/false: shape not present).

This process is ok, but not great. I have 4 forms with ~500 fields, and a mean of 70% accuracy. The output of this program is feeding a predictive model, and the forms' fields are strong predictor candidates, so I'd like to bump the correct/total ratio up a few notches (ideally > .90).

I've tried contour comparison, but this has been inaccurate due to poor scan quality, low ink levels on the scanned image, different lengths of vectors between markings/form types, etc.

So (finally!) my question is: Are any Open/Emgu CV experts out there who have some better ideas about how to detect markings on a scanned document? If the scenario and question are too vague, I'll gladly clear them up. Code samples (C++, C#, Python) are welcome.

Comment: This question may be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). That site's purpose is to take existing, working code, and make it better. Since your existing code works, just not as well as you'd like, consider removing this question and posting it over there (with your code) instead.

Comment: @ScottLawson I'm not sure this question is a good candidate for code review. The question is not really about the existing code (design patterns, best practices, etc).

Comment: You are much more likely to get a response if you post some sample images.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I got the impression that the OP has working code already. In particular, the line that says "This process is okay, but..." suggests that the OP has something that works but needs improved. I think it could go either way though, and I don't feel so strongly about it that I flagged it for migration, but did think it was worth mentioning an alternate location to get an answer if this SO post doesn't get the OP a solid answer.

Comment: Hi all, thanks very much for your responses. I'm unable to share the original scans, but will dummy some up and run the process over them/share them here & on Code Review -- will first need to think how to best do that. Best, Crazy